# SXA facet returned attributes in API call

Tags: sxa

I have viewed the results of the API that get the facet data and it returns the below :

```
{  
   "TotalTime":20,
   "QueryTime":18,
   "Signature":null,
   "Index":"sitecore_master_index",
   "Facets":[  
      {  
         "Key":"facet",
         "Name":"facet",
         "Values":[  
            {  
               "Name":"result4",
               "Count":1
            },
            {  
               "Name":"August 2017",
               "Count":1
            },
            {  
               "Name":"result1",
               "Count":1
            },
            {  
               "Name":"result2",
               "Count":2
            },
            {  
               "Name":"result3",
               "Count":1
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

can I extend the API to return an additional field other than Name and count?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no simple way to achieve that. You would need to modify `SearchController` and few more classes to achieve that. Believe me - you don't want to go that way.

If you really want your custom solution/custom structure of response I would suggest implementing new service for this. Take a look at `GetFacets()` method in `SearchController` and `FacetSet` class.

Comment: Thanks Dawid, what i need to achieve that i have a date column that i need to display it in format "MMM, yyyy" in dropdown so i thought of adding computed index field that will store the date formatted and display it in SXA facet dropdown but i need to sort this dropdown by the date value so i though of passing this from api as the name and the count, do you have any suggestions?